# adding subview on subviews of scrollview

Tags: ios, subview

I have added 20 subviews to scrollview line by line as rows.

**Code Snippet**

```
yPos=0;
for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    UIView *timeView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(71, yPos, 909, 60)];

    timeView.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;
    timeView.exclusiveTouch=YES;
    timeView.tag=i;

    NSLog(@"sub vieww tag=:%d",timeView.tag);

    timeView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    UILabel *lbltime=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 60)];
    lbltime.text=@"VIEW HERE";
    lbltime.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];

    [timeView addSubview:lbltime];

    [scrlView addSubview:timeView];

    yPos=yPos+61;
}
```

Now how do I add another subview on these 20 subviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have added all the view to your scroll
so,enumerate UIView from scrollview and add your anotherSubview to your UIView

```
for(UIView *myView in scrollview.subviews)
  {
   //Create UIView
   UIView *anotherSubView=[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];

   [myView addSubview:anotherSubview];
  }
```

Comment: ok with your answer ...but i want add anotherSubview on two subViews of scroll view.your answer is adding new view on only one sub view..

Comment: get your 2 subviews by comparing the tag you are assigning and add another subview to both the subviews.

Comment: sorry i am not getting...here i have 20 subviews on scroll view.now i have to add another subview on subviews of scroll view...

Comment: let me rephrase your question. you have 20 subviews on scrollview and now you want to add another subview on two subviews, out of 20 subviews on scrollview. Am i right?

Comment: ok so do the following:
1)iterate all the subviews of scroll
2)compare the subviews by the tag you are assigning(timeView.tag=i) , if (subview.tag = yourTagOfView){
//add another subview to the view
}
by this you are adding another subview only to your 2 subviews of scroll view

Comment: i tried that thing also.but the new subview is adding only on one view.see my code..for(UIView *myView in [scrlView subviews] )
    {
      if (myView.tag==viewId) {
            UIView *ssview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 80)];
    UILabel *recurenceId=[[UILabel alloc]init];
            ssview.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];        [ssview addSubview:recurenceId];
            [myView addSubview:ssview];
        }
     }
here ssview height is more than myview. then the ssview must be add to next subview of scroll view also.but it does not adding.

Comment: see this question also  on this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356624/how-to-add-subview-to-subviews-of-scroll-view]

Comment: because you are only comparing with one viewId. compare it with both the views  if (myView.tag==viewId1 or viewId2) . Or do two comparison if you want selective changes to both the views. `if (myView.tag==viewId1){ //your stuff for view 1 } elseif (myView.tag==viewId2){ //your stuff for view 2 }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
{
UIView *timeView=[self subViews] objectAtIndex:i];  // or super, I didn't underdtand question exactly

CGRect yourFrameOfSub=CGRectMake(0,0,10,10); //set your values
UIView *anotherSubview=[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:yourFrameOfSub];

[timeView addSubview:anotherSubview];

}
```

Comment: i need to add anotherSubview on Two subViews of scroll view.your answer is adding new view on only one sub view..

Comment: Then replace last line in my code on this line:
[timeView.subview addSubview:anotherSubview];
Or if you need, that and timeView and its' subview have a anotherSubview, then replace last line in my code on this two lines:
[timeView addSubview:anotherSubview];
[timeView.subview addSubview:anotherSubview];

Comment: i did i am getting an error...here timeview is subview of scroll view.then we have to add anotherSubview to scrollview subview or not?

Comment: No, we should add anotherSubview to timeView.subview and we have:
scrollview-->timeview-->lbltime-->anotherSubview  And if you want to get anotherSubview from time view you should: [timeview subview]subview] or: [timeview subviews] objectAtIndex:1]

Comment: Did you solute your problem?

Comment: no...please see this question also  on y=this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356624/how-to-add-subview-to-subviews-of-scroll-view]

Answer (score 0):

Keep an `NSMutableArray` and add all the reference in the first loop.Loop the array count and add the second view to the pointer references in array

Note : all the other answer might work if and only if that superview contains only that added views as subviews alone.If anyother view exist it will add a view in there also

Answer (score 0):

NSlog(@"Subviews : %@",self.scrollView.subviews);

```
for(UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews){

   // NSLog(@"View : %@",view);
    // you can add ur subview in this view
}
```