# how to add subview to subviews of scroll view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

[image: sample image]

how create this view.
code for adding scroll view

```
yPos=0;
for (int i=0; i<24; i++) {

    UIView *timeView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(71, yPos, 909, 60)];
    timeView.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;
    timeView.exclusiveTouch=YES;
    if (i==4) {
        UIView *ssview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 80)];
        ssview.tag=1;
        ssview.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;
        UILabel *recurenceId=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        recurenceId.text=@"A12334";

        [ssview addSubview:recurenceId];
        ssview.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];


        [timeView addSubview:ssview];
        [ssview addGestureRecognizer:tap];



    }
```

here ssview height is more than timeview.so it be added to next subview also

here every row is a subview of scroll view.
Now  i have to addd another view which is in green color.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: if added greenView in 12th row it must me add on 13th row according to its height..

Comment: so you want to change height of 12th row according to its subview???

Comment: no the heights of each row must be constant.If the height of adding subview is greater than 60 then the subview have to add 13th row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *greenViewsIndexes=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5],[NSNumber numberWithInt:6],[NSNumber numberWithInt:11],[NSNumber numberWithInt:12], nil];   
for (int i=0; i<24; i++) {

for (int j=0; j>greenViews.count; j++) {
if ([[greenViews objectAtIndex:j]intValue]==i){
    UIView *greenView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(71,61*(j+1),100,80)];
    [greenView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    }
  }

  //another operations

}
```

Comment: good answer...but i have only two index values 5 and 11.when i a subview added at index 5 with 80pixel height it must be overlap to 6th index also...but it not doing why  because each row height is 60pixel only....i think now you got my problem...

Comment: So you want add subview with 80 height on view with 60 and you must not change height 60 of view, right?

Comment: yes right.when we pass 80 height means the adding subview must be added on next subsequent subview also...

Answer (score 0):

I got you problem. It's not overlap your next cell, because your next cell lie on your previous cell and overlap previous cell's edge. Try to: remove cell (which will has a green view) from super view and add again with green view:

```
NSArray *greenViewsIndexes=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5],[NSNumber numberWithInt:11], nil];   
for (int i=0; i<greenViewsIndexes.count; i++) {
int j=[[greenViewsIndexes objectAtIndex:i]intValue];
[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperView]

UIView *timeView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(71, 61*(j+1), 909, 60)]; //set your values
timeView.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;
timeView.exclusiveTouch=YES;
UIView *greenView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(71,61*(j+1),100,80)];  //set yourValues
[greenView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[timeView addSubview:greenView];
[self.view addSubview:timeView];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your supporting... i am using ios6.1 .it showing error at removeFromSuperView..

Comment: What is you get, about this method?